# Azure AD custom administrator that can manage guest accounts

Tags: azure-active-directory

In the AAD there is no predefined administrator role that gives a user the right to manage only guest users. There is the "user administrator", but it can manage all users and not only guest users. Then there is the "guest inviter", which only has the right to invite guest users, but not to manage all aspects of them.

Is there a way to create a custom administrator role that has these rights?

The reason for this is that we have implemented a partner portal in SharePoint in my company. Our partners access the corresponding SharePoint pages via guest accounts. Therefore our partner managers should be able to manage only these partner/ guest users. They could do this via the AAD admin center, if there would be a suitable administrator role for it.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to create a custom administrator role that has these
>   rights?

Currently, the answer is no.

Now only permissions for Application registrations are supported in custom roles. More permissions are coming soon.

[image]